# Make an SKFieldNode affect an SKSpriteNode when the sprite's velocity is being explicitly set?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skfieldnode

I have a SpriteKit scene with an `SKFieldNode.linearGravityField(withVector:)` and an `SKSpriteNode` that has a `physicsBody`. The user moves the sprite with their finger.

I'm moving the sprite by explicitly setting its `velocity` in `update(_:)`, which causes a problem: the field doesn't affect the sprite when the user's finger is touching the screen because my code overrides it. When the user's finger is *not* touching the screen, the field works as desired.

Here's how I'm setting the sprite's `velocity`:

```
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    //NOTE: intensityX and intensityY are based on how far the user has dragged their finger, and are set in touchMoved().

    if intensityX != 0.0 {
        mainCharacter?.physicsBody?.velocity.dx = intensityX
    }
    if intensityY != 0.0 {
        mainCharacter?.physicsBody?.velocity.dy = intensityY
    }
}
```

And here's how I'm creating the field:

```
let field = SKFieldNode.linearGravityField(withVector: vector_float3(-9.0,0,0))

field.region = SKRegion(size: CGSize(width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight*0.1))
        
field.position = CGPoint(x: screenWidth, y: screenHeight*0.2)
        
addChild(field)
```

**Question:** How might I go about making it so the field affects the sprite even when the sprite is being moved by the user?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this problem is to apply some force to the sprite's `physicsBody` instead of explicitly setting its velocity. Explicitly setting  its velocity overrides the physics of the field, which is no good.

In `update(_:)`, I'm now using `applyForce(_:)`.

```
mainCharacter?.physicsBody?.applyForce(CGVector(dx: someForceX, dy: 0.0))
```

This allows the user to move the sprite while still experiencing the effects of the field.